# Matlab and normal realizations

Tags: matlab, matrix, histogram, probability, normal-distribution

I have wrote this code:.

```
N=10000; % number of experiments
o= 1000+randn(1,N)*sqrt(10^4); % random normal distribution with mean 1000 and variance 10^4
b=700:50:1300; % specify the number of bins (possible values of the realizations)
prob=hist(o,b)/N %create ad histogram
```

X=[700:50:1300]
**

Now, how I can create a matrix which contains the values of b and prob?
In other words, I want a matrix of this kind:

**matrix=[ value of X(i) ; probability associate at the value of X(i) ]**

es: matrix=[... X(i)=850... ; ... prob(X(i)=850).. ]

Thank you a lot! ;)

Comment: The probability associated to any _single_ value is 0. You should rethink what you want

Comment: It is not 0. If you run the script you obtain the probabilities. My only problem is to save it in a matrix.

Comment: It _is_ 0. Your script gives the probabilities of _intervals_

Comment: I have edit the post. It is more clear now?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I insist: the probability of a _value_ is 0. The probability of an _interval of values_ is more meaningful. See my answer; is that what you want?

Comment: It very useful :) but it is not what I want, because I had to generate random values of probabilities..

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the probabilities of the *intervals* for which the histogram is computed:

```
N = 100000; %// number of experiments
b = 700:50:1300; %// bin centers
mu = 1000; %// mean of distribution
sigma = 100; %// standard deviation of distribution

delta = (b(2)-b(1))/2; %// compute bin half-width
pb = normcdf(b+delta,mu,sigma)-normcdf(b-delta,mu,sigma); %// compute probability
```

Check:

```
o = mu + sigma*randn(1,N);
hist(o, b)
hold on
plot(b, N*pb, 'r', 'linewidth', 2)
```

[image]